# Extracting the maximum performance from the Hololens 2 using Unreal Engine

Tags: unreal-engine4, hololens

If we take the default level from the started content on Unreal Engine and package it onto the Hololens 2, the objects (chairs, tables, so on) shift in a jarring way during each frame. Other, simpler scenes are also subject to extreme jankyness when viewed in the Hololens 2.

I have went through various options in Project Settings but have not managed to extract more performance out of the device.

What are the standard ways to optimize levels designed in Unreal Engine when running them on the Hololens 2? How can we extract the maximum performance levels from the device?

Answer (score 1):

For recommended Unreal project settings, Microsoft provides a documentation show performance recommendations on features specific to Unreal Engine, you can refer this link:[Performance recommendations for Unreal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unreal/performance-recommendations-for-unreal).

Besides, [Performance Guidelines for Mobile Devices](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Platforms/Mobile/Performance/index.html) provided by Unreal also is a good guide for optimizing content and features for mobile apps.